# Does model.compile() initialize all the weights and biases in Keras (tensorflow backend)?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

When I start training a model, there is no model saved previously. I can use `model.compile()` safely. I have now saved the model in a `h5` file for further training using `checkpoint`.

Say, I want to train the model further. I am confused at this point: can I use `model.compile()` here? And should it be placed before or after the `model = load_model()` statement? If `model.compile()` reinitializes all the weights and biases, I should place it before `model = load_model()` statement.

After discovering some discussions, it seems to me that `model.compile()` is only needed when I have no model saved previously. Once I have saved the model, there is no need to use `model.compile()`. Is it true or false? And when I want to predict using the trained model, should I use `model.compile()` before predicting?

Answer (score 225, accepted):

**When to use?**

**If** you're using `compile`, surely it must be after `load_model()`. After all, you need a model to compile. (PS: `load_model` automatically compiles the model with the optimizer that was saved along with the model)

**What does `compile` do?**

Compile defines the **loss function**, the **optimizer** and the **metrics**. That's all.

It has nothing to do with the weights and you can compile a model as many times as you want without causing any problem to pretrained weights.

You need a compiled model to **train** (because training uses the loss function and the optimizer). But it's not necessary to compile a model for predicting.

**Do you need to use compile more than once?**

Only if:

- You want to change one of these:

  - Loss function
  - Optimizer / Learning rate
  - Metrics
  - The `trainable` property of some layer
- You loaded (or created) a model that is not compiled yet. Or your load/save method didn't consider the previous compilation.

**Consequences of compiling again:**

If you compile a model again, you will lose the **optimizer states**.

This means that your training will suffer a little at the beginning until it adjusts the learning rate, the momentums, etc. But there is absolutely no damage to the weights (unless, of course, your initial learning rate is so big that the first training step wildly changes the fine tuned weights).

Comment: Would use lose all optimizer states after a re-compile even when you initially saved the model with include_optimizer=True ?

Comment: You need to recompile with the same optimizer... but I'm not sure it's possible.

Comment: @DanielMöller : Does it affect `model.outputs` i.e, after compilation and before compilation what is the difference between the two? Also, would be great if you could explain the use of `compile=False` in `load_model(model, compile=False/True)` argument.

Comment: Nothing changes. Compiling is to set the "optimizer" and "loss" function for "training", that's all. If you want to load a model and you will not train it, you don't need to compile it. 1 - `compile=True`: the model will load and compile with the same settings as saved. 2 - `compile=False`, you will load only the model without optimizer.

Comment: @DanielMöller what about the common recommendation of using model.compile after changing the 'trainable' attribute of a layer? Is this covered in your points for when to use model compile? What about when changing the weights of a layer using 'set_weights()' ?

Comment: Thank you for reminding me of `trainable`. But there is no problem at all with setting weights.

Comment: Can I reuse an instance of `Optimizer` (instead of passing "adam") to prevent its state from being reset when recompiling the model? I need to change `trainable` on a few layers in the middle.

Comment: @LOST, yes, you can,

Comment: @DanielMöller Hi. Ok, so how can I load a TensorFlow model to retrain it without the optimizer states being reset? I just asked this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77341956/how-to-load-a-tensorflow-model-to-retrain-it-without-the-optimizer-states-being. Thanks.

Answer (score 35):

Don't forget that you also need to compile the model after changing the `trainable` flag of a layer, e.g. when you want to fine-tune a model like this:

1. load VGG model without top classifier
2. freeze all the layers (i.e. `trainable = False`)
3. add some layers to the top
4. compile and train the model on some data
5. un-freeze some of the layers of VGG by setting `trainable = True`
6. compile the model again (DON'T FORGET THIS STEP!)
7. train the model on some data

Comment: What would be the result of not compiling the model after changing a layer's trainable flag?

Comment: @Kake_Fisk The change would not be effective, i.e. the trainability status of the layer would remain as it was before the last `compile` method invocation.