# Change loss function dynamically during training in Keras, without recompiling other model properties like optimizer

Tags: python, keras, callback, epoch, loss

Is it possible to set `model.loss` in a callback without re-compiling `model.compile(...)` after (since then the optimizer states are reset), and just recompiling `model.loss`, like for example:

```py
class NewCallback(Callback):

        def __init__(self):
            super(NewCallback,self).__init__()

        def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
            self.model.loss=[loss_wrapper(t_change, current_epoch=epoch)]
            self.model.compile_only_loss() # is there a version or hack of 
                                           # model.compile(...) like this?
```

**To expand more with previous examples on stackoverflow:**

To achieve a loss function which depends on the epoch number, like (as in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55406146/resume-training-with-different-loss-function/55978428#55978428)):

```py
def loss_wrapper(t_change, current_epoch):
    def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        c_epoch = K.get_value(current_epoch)
        if c_epoch < t_change:
            # compute loss_1
        else:
            # compute loss_2
    return custom_loss
```

where "current_epoch" is a Keras variable updated with a callback:

```py
current_epoch = K.variable(0.)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=loss_wrapper(5, current_epoch), 
metrics=...)

class NewCallback(Callback):
    def __init__(self, current_epoch):
        self.current_epoch = current_epoch

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        K.set_value(self.current_epoch, epoch)
```

One can essentially turn python code into compositions of backend functions for the loss to work as follows:

```py
def loss_wrapper(t_change, current_epoch):
    def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        # compute loss_1 and loss_2
        bool_case_1=K.less(current_epoch,t_change)
        num_case_1=K.cast(bool_case_1,"float32")
        loss = (num_case_1)*loss_1 + (1-num_case_1)*loss_2
        return loss
    return custom_loss
it works.
```

I am not satisfied with these hacks, and wonder, is it possible to set `model.loss` in a callback without re-compiling `model.compile(...)` after (since then the optimizer states are reset), and just recompiling `model.loss`?

Comment: Did you solve this? Do you need to keep the whole optimizer state or just weights? If just weights, perhaps save them, recompile, then load them. There's Model.load_weights(..., by_name=True) to load into a different model to what they were saved from. There's also saving/loading whole state like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503748/save-and-load-model-optimizer-state but I'm not sure if it allows you to change the architecture at all.

Comment: Did you find any solutions to this ? I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: I think using dynamic computational graph or `eager execution` mode with `tf 2.0` will solve this issue [eager execution](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager)

Comment: I don't find it too hacky to have a single loss function cased out by epoch, per your last approach.  You can also use model.add_loss() to do a similar thing without using a wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have found a solution to your problem by now but using tensorflow I think you can solve this by building a custom training loop ([here is the doc](https://keras.io/guides/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch/)). this will not override the loss attribute as you requested however you can probably achieve what you are looking for.

### example

#### initializing variable

modifying the example from the documentation, with a model and dataset as such:

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(784,), name="digits")
x1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(inputs)
x2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(x1)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, name="predictions")(x2)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)


# Prepare the training dataset.
batch_size = 64
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (-1, 784))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (-1, 784))
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(batch_size)
```

we can define our two loss functions (the two I chose make no sense from a scientific point of view but allow us to check the code works)

```
# Instantiate an optimizer.
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)
# Instantiate a loss function.
loss_1 = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
loss_2 = lambda y_true, y_pred: -1 * loss_1(y_true, y_pred)
```

#### training loop

we can then execute our custom training loop:

```
epochs = 10
for epoch in range(epochs):
    print("\nStart of epoch %d" % (epoch,))

    # Iterate over the batches of the dataset.
    for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(train_dataset):

        # Open a GradientTape to record the operations run
        # during the forward pass, which enables auto-differentiation.
        loss_fn = loss_1 if epoch % 2 else loss_2
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

            # Run the forward pass of the layer.
            # The operations that the layer applies
            # to its inputs are going to be recorded
            # on the GradientTape.
            logits = model(x_batch_train, training=True)  # Logits for this minibatch

            # Compute the loss value for this minibatch.
            loss_value = loss_fn(y_batch_train, logits)

        # Use the gradient tape to automatically retrieve
        # the gradients of the trainable variables with respect to the loss.
        grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)

        # Run one step of gradient descent by updating
        # the value of the variables to minimize the loss.
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
         # Log every 200 batches.
        if step % 200 == 0:
            print(
                "Training loss (for one batch) at step %d: %.4f"
                % (step, float(loss_value))
            )
            print("Seen so far: %s samples" % ((step + 1) * 64))
```

and we check the output is what we want (alternate positive and negative losses)

```
Start of epoch 0
Training loss (for one batch) at step 0: -96.1003
Seen so far: 64 samples
Training loss (for one batch) at step 200: -3383849.5000
Seen so far: 12864 samples
Training loss (for one batch) at step 400: -40419124.0000
Seen so far: 25664 samples
Training loss (for one batch) at step 600: -149133008.0000
Seen so far: 38464 samples
Training loss (for one batch) at step 800: -328322816.0000
Seen so far: 51264 samples

Start of epoch 1
Training loss (for one batch) at step 0: 580457984.0000
Seen so far: 64 samples
Training loss (for one batch) at step 200: 297710528.0000
Seen so far: 12864 samples
Training loss (for one batch) at step 400: 213328544.0000
Seen so far: 25664 samples
Training loss (for one batch) at step 600: 159328976.0000
Seen so far: 38464 samples
Training loss (for one batch) at step 800: 105737024.0000
Seen so far: 51264 samples
```

### drawbacks and further improvments

the problem with writing custom loops as such is that you will loose the convenience of keras's `fit` method. I think you can manage this by defining a custom model and overriding the `train_step` as shown [here](https://keras.io/guides/customizing_what_happens_in_fit/) in the documentation

If you really need to have the `loss` attribute of your model changed, you can set the `compiled_loss` attribute using a `keras.engine.compile_utils.LossesContainer` ([here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2c48a3b38b6b6139be2da501982fd2f61d7d48fe/keras/engine/compile_utils.py#L100) is the reference) and set `model.train_function` to `model.make_train_function()` (so that the new loss gets taken into account).