# How to dynamically change loss function between epochs in tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I want to change loss function for every alternative epoch or every 5 epochs. I tried using loss wrapper method suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55406146/resume-training-with-different-loss-function/55978428#55978428). This didn't work. It is keeping **current_epoch** value initialized forever and updated value is not coming in the loss wrapper function although this variable is updated for every epoch end in the **on_epoch_end** callback.

And also I tried using **model.add_loss** method in **on_epoch_end** callback. This is also not working. It takes only the loss function whatever is initialized in **model.compile**. It doesn't take the loss function passed in **model.add_loss**.

Answer (score 0):

Just compile the model multiple times:

```
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    if epoch % 2 == 0:
        current_loss_fn = loss_fn_1
    else:
        current_loss_fn = loss_fn_2
    model.compile(optimizer=current_optimizer, loss=current_loss_fn)
    train...
```

Comment: can you please share full code example if possible.

Comment: Do you know how to create a model a generate a training loop? The former would go above the code provided and the latter in the "train..." section. If you're not sure how to do those there are plenty of resources.