# Save two models in two differents folders

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm using two differents neural networks sequential models in my python program.

One RNN model defined like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, CuDNNLSTM

ModelRNN = Sequential()

ModelRNN.add(CuDNNLSTM(150, return_sequences=True, batch_size=None, input_shape=(None,10)))
ModelRNN.add(CuDNNLSTM(150, return_sequences=True))
ModelRNN.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
ModelRNN.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)

ModelRNN.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

One Dense model defined like this :

```
ModelDense = Sequential()

ModelDense.add(Dense(380, batch_size=None, input_shape=(1,380), activation='elu'))
ModelDense.add(Dense(380, activation='elu'))
ModelDense.add(Dense(380, activation='elu'))
ModelDense.add(Dense(380, activation='elu'))
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.00025)

ModelDense.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

So my problem is that the two networks will work together so i have to run both of them in the same tensorflow session **BUT**, i want to save them in two differents folders. 
I don't really know if it's possible because i never really interested myself in how is working the tensorflow graphs at all and i only know that when i use my tensorflow saver, i only give as parameter my session and a path.

So my question is how can i separate the storage of my models in two folders ?

> I want to do that because i want to be able to easily change my RNN without having to retrain both of my networks or without having to overwrite my trained RNN

**If i'am not clear please ask me for more details**

Comment: Nowhere in this code you are saving the models, please add that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my question is how can i separate the storage of my models in two
>   folders ?

The `save` method of Keras model accepts a file path, so different folders can be given for the individual models.

```
ModelRNN.save('folder1/<filename.h5>')
ModelDense.save('folder2/<filename.h5>')
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_restore_models#save_the_entire_model

Comment: oh really ! there is such a function ! thank a lot i didn't find anything about this i'll check it so thank a lot

Comment: So I tested it, the save function seems to work well but when i restore the model for retrain it the accuracy start with as bad values as if i create a new network..

Comment: This has to be a separate question. You can check if you compiled the model after loading, which is not required. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56851288/why-is-adam-iterations-always-set-to-0-in-keras/